JMeter simulation for larger data while having actually smaller dataset
So I have a GET API. In DB we have only 100 records. Now I need to test execution time, load time etc when our API asked to serve 10000 records all at once.
So for this in JMeter I have done this following configuration:
Number of Threads : 1
Ramp up period: 1
Loop count: 100

Now my confusion is if I hit the simple get-request from postman Im getting the result in  around 8sec and size is around 4mbs. Now with the above Jmeter config I checked the load time is around 6sec and Size in bytes:4669744. So I belive I haven't hit 10000 records otherwise Size would be increased. Am I correct? And how can I achieve 10000 records performance without manually inputting 10000 data in DB?


4669744 bytes is "around 4mbs"
With your setup you run 100 sequential requests, not 10000 concurrent requests

If you have 100 entries in DB and want to execute 10000 concurrent requests it means that each record will be fetched 100 times and you can get false positive results due to caching on DB and/or application server sides
So if you want to just run 10000 requests at the same time you will need to set "Number of Threads" to 10000. Additionally you might want to add a Synchronizing Timer to make sure that requests are being executed at exactly the same moment.
Having 10000 concurrent requests might require additional configuration on JMeter side, make sure to follow JMeter Best Practices and recommendations from 9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure article

What value should I add in the Synchronizing Timer ?

If you want 10000 concurrent requests you should use the same number in the synchronizing timer

Understood. Can you please confirm whether by hitting by 10000 concurrent requests will simulate having 10000 data in my DB? Just want to make sure again...I totally got your point btw
